# how to remove exif data in node.js

Tags: node.js, exif

I am using node.js express app with mongodb. If client upload an portrait image using their iphone, then in browser or andriod phone it will displayed as landscape. 
So can anyone tell me how can I remove EXIF data in node.js
Please give some example code.

I have referred this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28999829/how-to-strip-image-metadata-in-the-browser-before-upload-javascript) but I did not understand that

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=remove+exif

Answer (score 6):

There's a library for this - https://www.npmjs.com/package/piexifjs
With it you can edit the EXIF data in the binary and overwrite it with empty data if you wish.

Comment: Can you please give some example to remove exif data using above plugin file... because I have tried.. I dont know how can I do it.. I am beginner